# Dynamic number of buttons on GWT UI

Tags: gwt

I have a MVP type application where I will have a view that contains one or more buttons.  The number of buttons is not known till run time and may vary each time the page is rendered.  What is the best way to approach this apart from a simple loop that will just display 1 - n  number of buttons that are passed to the view?

Comment: What are you considering wrong in passing the number of button to the view whiwh will be instanciate this number of object?

Comment: It's not that I think there is anything wrong with passing in a list of button objects but as my GWT UI skills are limited I figured because that would be the most obvious way that maybe there is a better way a more experienced GWT developer would use

Comment: I would say that there is no better approach. You do it dynamically depending on your data model or other parameter. How you organize your code around that is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Add all the buttons on creation and use CSS to hide or show them dynamically. I think this will yield less DOM manipulations and still works the same, also it might produce a simpler code. I currently do it that way using SmartGwt.